# How to read an .h5 file from xmsd2 using Python correctly?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, spyder, h5py

I am using the xmds2 software and its outputs seems to be an h5 file.
I would like to use python (spyder) software to make possible to plot them into a 2d and 3d graphs.

The problem is that I can't realize how do it at all.
The code I run in Spyder is the following:

```
import numpy as np

import h5py

with h5py.File(r'Path...\lorenz.h5','r') as hdf:


      ls=list(hdf.keys())

      print('List of datasets in this file: \n', ls)
```

the only output I get is

```
  ['1']
```

So I would think that there is a column or something whose name is '1'

The question here is that my program in xmds2 outputs xR,yR,zR (and time I guess) non anything called '1' So I am really confused about what to do in order plot or load them into my python program correctly

I am newbie at using xmds2 so if someone could help me I would be grateful. And also this is the first time I have to deal with an .h5 file.

The program I run in xmds2 is here
http://www.xmds.org/tutorial.html

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your example

Comment: Fixed! I didn't notice , sorry

Comment: Based on value from `hdf.keys()`, you **_may_** only have one dataset (named '1'). Datasets are like NumPy arrays. Try `print (hdf5['1'].dtype)` and see what you get.

Comment: Well, thanks, I could solve that correctly without any problems.